# How to mix "sha1sum mismatch"

Tags: permissions, wine, directory, steam

I am trying to use winetricks to install steam on a 64 bit wine prefix, and I keep coming across this issue: 
`sha1sum mismatch!  Rename /home/wilton/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamSetup.exe and try again`
I tried renaming the SteamSetup.exe to SteamSetup.exe.bak, but when I ran        `winetricks steam`
 in the terminal, it added a file in the steam folder that was named "SteamSetup.exe", like the original. I am looking for help on renaming the file, or changing my Wine prefix to 64 bit. Please help.